# VB.NET Conversion problem when trying to convert from base class to subclass (BC30311: "Value of type '<type1>' cannot be converted to '<type2>'")

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, casting

Please take a look at the following code:

```
Public Sub Method(Of TEntity As EntityObject)(ByVal entity As TEntity)
    If TypeOf entity Is Contact Then  
        Dim contact As Contact = entity 'Compile error'
        Dim contact = DirectCast(entity, Contact) 'Compile error' 
        Dim contact = CType(entity, Contact) 'Compile error'
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one of the following works, I guess I will use the first one:

```
Dim contact As Contact = DirectCast(entity, Object) 
Dim contact As Contact = Convert.ChangeType(entity, TypeCode.Object)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should not give you a compile error and should properly cast it to the type you are looking for:

```
Dim contact As Contact = TryCast(entity, Contact)
```

Comment: You are wrong my friend, the compile error is thrown by the DirectCast function.

Comment: Why won't you try your answers before you post them?